# How can I achieve a grungy melting effect on a vector file? [with photo example]

Tags: photoshop-effects, illustrator-effects

Seen this for a while now on the web, & was wondering how to achieve this effect or something similar. Looking forward for your answers!

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Have you tried the [liquify filter](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/liquify-filter.html) in Photoshop?

Comment: Let's say I get this liquid effect on photoshop, with a portrait. How do I turn it then into this grungy vector?

Comment: There's nothing that looks vector at all. It looks like someone used the threshold filter on a photograph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a liquidated image. OK. Trace it to two colors in Illustrator or Inkscape. That's Black & White tracing. The particles  will be generated if your image is noisy. Smooth gradients will become full of particles near the treshold brightness. I have inserted noise to make it stronger.